# get innerHTML of the children of the currentTarget

Tags: javascript

I have this part of my html (more than one of same type):

```
<div class="this-product">
 <img src="images/bag2.jpeg" alt="">
 <span class="product-name">iPhone</span>
 <span class="product-price">345445</span>
</div>
```

And this part of my javascript code meant to get the innerHTML of the span tags and assign them values as shown:

```
var productList = document.querySelectorAll('.this-product');
productList.forEach(function (element) {

    element.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        var productName = document.getElementsByClassName('product-name')[0].innerHTML;
        var productPrice = document.getElementsByClassName('product-price')[0].innerHTML;
        var cartProductname = event.currentTarget.productName;
        var cartProductprice = event.currentTarget.productPrice;
        var cartContent = '<div class="cart-product"><span class="block">'+cartProductname+'</span><span class="block">'+cartProductprice+'</span></div><div class="cart-result">Total = </div><br>'
        document.getElementById('dashboard-cart').innerHTML += cartContent;
    });
});
```

Everything works well and every variable above has its value shown well apart from **cartProductname** and **cartProductprice** which display as **undefined** and also vscode tells me that productName is declared but not read. Where could I be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could call `querySelector` on each product item element that you are iterating like so:

```
var productList = document.querySelectorAll('.this-product');
productList.forEach(function (element) {

    element.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

        // Update these two lines like so:
        var productName = element.querySelector('.product-name').innerHTML;
        var productPrice = element.querySelector('.product-price').innerHTML;

        var cartProductname = productName; // event.currentTarget.productName;
        var cartProductprice = productPrice; // event.currentTarget.productPrice;
        var cartContent = '<div class="cart-product"><span class="block">'+cartProductname+'</span><span class="block">'+cartProductprice+'</span></div><div class="cart-result">Total = </div><br>'
        document.getElementById('dashboard-cart').innerHTML += cartContent;
    });
});
```

Comment: Also an awesome one. Edit your answer by removing the [0] after ('.product-price') to make it correct.

Comment: @EricO. great - thanks for the feedback! Hope this has helped you with your project :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `event.currentTarget.querySelector('.product-name')` to get element inside of another element

Comment: Wow. You are awesome.